# Creating temp table which duplicates values of one column but changes the value of another colum

Tags: sql, rows, temp-tables

I have table Z with 2 columns:

[image]

I need to add 2 more types: C and D where the Total value is equal to A and B respectively and make a new temp X table like this:
[image]

I want to use the logic where the Total value of C is equal to A and the total Value of D is equal to B instead of using the insert into function where I state the value of C as 12 and D as 15 because the original Total value for table Z will keep changing; hence, I don't want to manually insert the new values every time. I also don't have the authority to create new tables in the database so table Z is derived from a select statement and I can't create new permanent tables. So I am hoping to create a temp table of table Z.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `union all`.  I'm not sure if aggregation is needed, but this calculates the total for all As and Bs:

```
insert into x (type, total)
    select 'C', sum(total)
    from x
    where type = 'A'
    union all
    select 'D', sum(total)
    from x
    where type = 'B';
```

Or if aggregation is not necessary, a `case` expression allows a single scan of the data:

```
insert into x (type, total)
    select (case when type = 'A' then 'C' else 'D' end), total
    from x
    where type in ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: Hi Gordon! I appreciate your quick response. Won't table x only have two rows with C and D as the types? I also need type A and B to be in the table.

Comment: @BSR . . . No.  `INSERT` adds them to the existing rows.